# Kineticjs image sometimes showing on top and sometimes not

Tags: canvas, kineticjs

I am new to Kineticjs and I am creating a canvas with three images, 1) Background image 2) Play icon 3) Pause icon.

One play icon will be there on the background image, when I click the play icon it will be replaced with pause icon and mp3 will played in the background. Here my problem is everything is working fine as I expected except one. i.e., when I load the page sometimes the play icon appearing on top of the background image and sometimes going behind to the background image. Don't know why?

Please help to show always the play icon on the top of the background image. Thanks in advance.

```
 var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 1025,
        height: 770
        });
        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
        stage.add(layer);

        var sources = {
            bgimg: {'img_src':'bg.png','x':'0','y':'0','w':'1024','h':'768','id':'bg'},
        };


        $.each(sources, function(key, value){ 
            var imageObj = new Image();
            imageObj.src = value['img_src'];
            imageObj.onload = function() {
                var image = new Kinetic.Image({
                    x: value['x'],
                    y: value['y'],
                    image: imageObj,
                    width: value['w'],
                    height: value['h']
                });

                layer.add(image);
                layer.draw();
            };
        });

        var pauseImageObj = new Image();
        pauseImageObj.src = 'pause.png';
        var paused = false;

        var playImageObj = new Image();
        playImageObj.onload = function() {
            var playImage = new Kinetic.Image({
                x: 500,
                y: 500,
                image: playImageObj,
                width: 64,
                height: 64,
                id: 'play'
            });

            layer.add(playImage);
            layer.draw();

            playImage.on('click', function() {
                if(paused == false){
                    layer.get('#play')[0].setImage(pauseImageObj);
                    paused = true;
                }else{
                    layer.get('#play')[0].setImage(playImageObj);
                    paused = false;
                }
                   layer.draw();
                   togglePlay();
            });

        };
        playImageObj.src = 'play.png';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting `Kinetic.Image` after images loaded. But any of you image may load first (button or background).
You can use this:

```
background.moveToBottom();
```

or

```
button.moveToTop();
```

Comment: I am little confused, where to add the code to my script? Plz put the lines in my script.

Comment: add `image.moveToButtom();` after `layer.add(image);`

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle demo?